# Capture multiple values from a tag <select> in a String vector

Tags: jquery, spring

In my spring application, I have an html form with a  which needs to send values serverside. 
The code in the JSP page to send the values to server is:

**html form**

```
<form name="form_lista_horario">
    <select name="id_evento" id="id_evento">
        <c:forEach var="evento" items="${lista_eventos}">
          <option value="<c:out value="${evento.id}"/>"> ${evento.nome} - ${evento.descricao} </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>

    <table id="hor-zebra" border = 2>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="lista_usuarios" id="usuarios" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                <c:forEach var="usuario" items="${lista_usuarios}">
                    <option value="${usuario.id}">${usuario.nome}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </td>

    <td>
        <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="for_left"> << </button> </p>
        <p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="for_right"> >> </button> </p>
    </td>

        <td>
            <select name="selecao_usuarios" id="selecao" size="10" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="btn_enviar">OK</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "lista_horario.html",
        data: { id_evento: $('#id_evento option:selected').val(), id_usuarios: $('#selecao option').val()  },
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#result").show();
        $("#result").empty().append( data );
    });
});
```

This data is read by this method from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/lista_horario", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String lista_horario(@RequestParam("id_evento") String id_evento, @RequestParam("id_usuarios") String[] id_usuarios)
{
     ...
    }
```

My problem is this method is reading only the first value of the . Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

Ok, problem not entirely solved yet. Sorry, I realize don't make enough tests. Now, when I try submit the form to server, the console of the browser show this is being sent:

```
**id_evento:"1"**
```

and

```
id_usuario[] 9
id_usuario[] 4
id_usuario[] 7
id_usuario[] 8
**_:"1395536033181"**;
```

only the first parameter is being sent correctly.

My jquery code now is this:

```
$("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
    var selecao_usuario=[];
    $('#selecao option').each(function(){
        selecao_usuario.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "lista_horario.html",
        data: { id_evento: $('#id_evento option:selected').val(), id_usuarios: selecao_usuario },
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#result").show();
        $("#result").empty().append( data );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var id_evento_valores=[];
$('#id_evento option:selected').each(function() {
id_evento_valores.push($(this).val());
});

//..

 $.ajax({
        url: "lista_horario.html",
        data: { id_evento: id_evento_valores, id_usuarios: $('#selecao option').val()  },
        //...
```

or if you want it as a comma seperated list instead of an array

```
var id_evento_valores=[];
    $('#id_evento option:selected').each(function() {
    id_evento_valores.push($(this).val());
    });

var id_evento_cuerda=id_evento_valores.join(",");
//..
```

Comment: Ok, actually I am trying submit multiple values for <select> identifient by id 'selecao_usuarios', but with this I can adapt the code for my use. thank you.

Comment: I see. Interesting problem. Glad this guy had an answer for you.

Comment: Ok, problem not entirely solved yet. Sorry, I realize don't make enough tests. Now, when I try submit the form to server, the console of the browser show this is being sent: **id_evento:"1"** and **_:"1395536033181"**; only the first parameter is being sent correctly.

Comment: update the question with a even more recent console message and the changed jquery code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select name="id_evento" id="id_evento" multiple>
    <c:forEach var="evento" items="${lista_eventos}">
      <option value="<c:out value="${evento.id}"/>"> ${evento.nome} - ${evento.descricao} </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

See what it does. It should allow for multi-select which will separate the selected values with a comma.

Comment: Actually, the data I have multiple values to submit to server is stored in the <select> identified by id 'selecao_usuarios', not 'id_evento'.

Comment: So you 'can' select multiple options? You just can't see the additional values? Can you dump out your posted form variables? The way I understand form key/value pairs is that that 'anything' with a name (even another form type), will end up in comma separated value string for the form variable.